# General/ number cell is displayed with hash characters (MS Excel 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm familiar with cells being hashed out for a variety of reasons but I've don't know what is happening here.

I have set the cell format to Number with no decimals and also tried general.  I am inputting a single whole number but it appears hashed, (see below)

[image: excel]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried making the cell wider?

Comment: @MaherFattouh The cell is more than wide enough to display the number `2`! (hint: next time look at the screenshot)

Comment: @MaherFattouh  Just tried it, font calibri; size; value 2.  If I sett he width to 15.11, it appears, really strange.  There are much bigger numbers above it. don't understand it all.

Comment: This generally happens when you give a cell a specific format and Excel feels it doesn't fit in view.

Comment: Align Left was causing, I un-clicked it. Really weird, maybe this is a bug?  Do you want to put that in as the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align left was set on the cell.

No idea why this caused the problem but it did.

Un-clicking align left resolved the issue.